# Keras breaks Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, keras, anaconda

I am switching from tensorflow to keras on my Anaconda distribution and am having some problems with the latter. I install it through Anaconda prompt with the command

```
conda install keras
```

and I do not think the installation is properly finished since it runs the command

```
python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
```

and closes the prompt. Afterwards, if I am to open the command line it automatically runs the command above and closes it, so I am unable to use the prompt. This has happened for both Anaconda 5.3.1 (Python 3.7) and Anaconda 5.2.0 (Python 3.6).

Thank you very much in advance. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Keras uses a backend like tensorflow ot theano, which one you use for?

Comment: I am using Tensorflow @Geeocode

Comment: As tensorflow prefer installing via pip in anaconda environment, you should try to install both tf and Keras with pip. I used this method and works perfectly. Actually you're not the first who struggles with conda type install of tf and Keras. I use conda install for any applications which is possible for, but tf and Keras are not such. But it is important: use the Anaconda virtualenv and inside of it you have to use pip!

Comment: Please refer to this link. Using this answer, you'll be able to run anaconda prompt again and do whatever you want:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53488063/anaconda-prompt-stuck-closing-after-keras-installation/54237245#54237245

Comment: In my case, following the answer given by amanrs in [this github issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/13209#issuecomment-546056765) solved the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I figured out the answer after combining answers from GAURAV and GYAN ARORA. The solution is this:

1) Go to `%UserProfile%Anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d`and right click on `keras_activate.bat`
2) Click on edit. This is what the .bat file looks like:

```
:: Figure out the default Keras backend by reading the config file.
python %CONDA_PREFIX%\etc\keras\load_config.py > temp.txt
set /p KERAS_BACKEND=<temp.txt
del temp.txt

:: Try to use the default Keras backend.
:: Fallback to Theano if it fails (Theano always works).
python -c "import keras" 1>nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    ver > nul
    set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
    python -c "import keras" 1>nul 2>&1
)
```

Change both `1>nul` to `1>`. The final file should look like this:

```
:: Figure out the default Keras backend by reading the config file.
python %CONDA_PREFIX%\etc\keras\load_config.py > temp.txt
set /p KERAS_BACKEND=<temp.txt
del temp.txt

:: Try to use the default Keras backend.
:: Fallback to Theano if it fails (Theano always works).
python -c "import keras" 1> 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
    ver > nul
    set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
    python -c "import keras" 1> 2>&1
)
```

3) Save and close

Comment: Actually, it's better to remove `1> nul` altogether. The resulting batch code suggested above, `1> 2>&1`, is not valid syntax and will result in the error message "2>&1 was unexpected at this time.` What the original batch code is trying to do is suppress all output of the command (i.e., by redirecting stdout to `nul` and stderr to stdout), but for some reason, Anaconda Prompt doesn't like/support `nul`, so it was throwing an error and exiting. But by just removing `nul`, you are creating incorrect batch code.

Comment: `1>nul 2>&1` print the standard errors and standard output to a single file (here to `NUL`) [refer here for detailed explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/redirecting-error-command-prompt)

Answer (score 7):

I tried almost every solution to this problem (erasing "nul" from activate.d seemed to work at first, but then conda commands related to packages still crashed the prompt). So this is what I did. The problems seems to originate in the way that conda installs keras.

1) Uninstall keras [using pip](https://datatofish.com/pip-uninstall-package/). Use the Scripts folder in the Anaconda installation folder.

2) Manually delete every remaining folder from Keras. Most of them are located in the Anaconda installation folder. Don't forget to delete the `keras_activate.bat` and `keras_deactive.bat` files in the `activate.d` and `deactivate.d` folders.

3) Install keras using pip.

4) That solves the `activate.d` problem. However, Anaconda Prompt still crashes because of the other file in the `%UserProfile%Anaconda3/etc/conda` folder, which is called `vs2015_compiler_vars.bat`. Delete that file and everything will work just fine (weird error messages that appeared while using Keras will also go away).

P.S. I went through one extra step to make Anaconda Prompt work perfectly, but I don't know if it is related to installing Keras (that's the reason why I am not including it in the answer). As conda commands were getting stuck in "Solving environment", I enabled strich channel priority with `conda config --set channel_priority strict`. Now Anaconda is totally functional!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, took me 2 days to finally get things working and many re-installs. This message comes from the following file. `%UserProfile%Anaconda3/etc/conda/activate.d/keras_activate.bat.`  There is some issue in the code written in this file which closes the Anaconda prompt every time. I dont know how to solve it, perhaps someone else can suggest something, but one way to still do some essential tasks on your prompt window is -> RIGHT CLICK ON THE ABOVE MENTIONED FILE AND SELECT EDIT -> WRITE YOUR ANACONDA PROMPT COMMAND AT THE TOP OF THE FILE. (It will execute and then close.)

Answer (score 1):

IN below line in .bat file nul is creating the problem and it is closing the terminal please remove nul and this will be solved. So change this

```
python -c "import keras" 1>nul 2>&1
```

to this

```
python -c "import keras" 1> 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I didn't find a permanent fix, but before the script finishes running, you can escape it using `ctrl+d`, and you should be able to do whatever you want after that.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was ,

1.Uninstall Keras first

2.goto the location 
`C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\etc\conda\activate.d`

You can see the keras batch files inside in both `activate.d` and `deactivate.d`, which runs every time the anaconda prompt is `opened.DELETE` them.

3.Reinstall Keras.

This worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Simply execute command:
pip unistall keras

And delete activate.d and deactivate.d from
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\etc\conda\

And reopen Anaconda prompt

Answer (score 0):

`"> Change both 1>nul to 1>"` - Did not worked for me...

But this fixed the issue:

1. uninstall Keras      `pip uninstall keras`
2. go to `C:\Users\<username>\anaconda3\etc\conda` and DELETE all files in these folders
3. install Keras  `pip install keras`

Answer (score 0):

I execute the anaconda prompt under administrator right and remove/reinstall Keras. The problem is then solved.

However it still gives me Theano backend that I need to manually changed it.