# anaconda prompt always start with these set of commands upon launch after installing keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, anaconda, conda

I am using anaconda 2018.2 on Windows 10. After installing keras using conda on "Anaconda Prompt", I encounter a weird problem. Whenever "Anaconda Prompt" is launched, it executes a set of commands automatically. Whenever any conda command is run, it also runs the same set of commands.

How do I remove this set of irritating commands from "Anaconda Prompt"? Thank you.

The commands look like this as shown below;

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>python C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\etc\keras\load_config.py  1>temp.txt

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set /p KERAS_BACKEND= 0<temp.txt

C:\WINDOWS\system32>del temp.txt

C:\WINDOWS\system32>python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if errorlevel 1 (
ver  1>nul
 set "KERAS_BACKEND=theano"
 python -c "import keras"  1>nul 2>&1
)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET MSSdk=1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET platform=

C:\WINDOWS\system32>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\" )

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\" == "" (
ECHO "Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - exiting"
 exit 1
)

C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo "Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
"Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET "VS_VERSION=14.0"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET "VS_MAJOR=14"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET "VS_YEAR=2015"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\vcruntime140.dll"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "CFLAGS= -MD -GL"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "CXXFLAGS= -MD -GL"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set "LDFLAGS_SHARED= -LTCG ucrt.lib"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>IF /I [] == [win-64] (set "folder=x64" )  else (set "folder=x86" )

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\*1*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "10" == "8.1" set win=10

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (8.1) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "8.1" == "8.1" set win=8.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\*1*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "10" == "10" set win=10

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (8.1) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "8.1" == "10" set win=8.1

C:\WINDOWS\system32>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

C:\WINDOWS\system32>if "10" == "10" (
for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do set last=%A
 set "sdk_bin_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\!last!\x86"
)  else (set "sdk_bin_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86" )

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10.0.14393.0) do set last=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set last=10.0.14393.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10.0.15063.0) do set last=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set last=10.0.15063.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10.0.16299.0) do set last=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set last=10.0.16299.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10.0.17134.0) do set last=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set last=10.0.17134.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>for %A in (10.0.17763.0) do set last=%A

C:\WINDOWS\system32>set last=10.0.17763.0

C:\WINDOWS\system32>endlocal   & set "PATH=C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\Library\usr\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\Library\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\bin;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\condabin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.0\libnvvp;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\libnvvp;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.37\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nordic Semiconductor\nrf5x\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.35\bin;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.2\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.2.1.38\cuda\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\young\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\young\Dropbox\PortableApps\PortableApps\ConsolePortable\Data\scripts;C:\Users\young\.windows-build-tools\python27\;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\young\Dropbox\PortableApps\PortableApps\ConsolePortable\Data\scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\young\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\young\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_2018_2\lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.17763.0\x86"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>SET "CMAKE_GENERATOR=Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64
```

Comment: You should report these issues to the anaconda people

Comment: Anaconda have lot of issues with `keras`. Please look this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483685/keras-breaks-anaconda-prompt). This might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using windows:

Keras uses tensorflow and it in turn depends on VC++ build tools. Follow the below steps

1. Open the Microsoft Visual Studio link: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
2. Select ‘Community version 2019’
3. Download the installer and select VC++ Build tools on the list

Also it is suggested to create a virtual environment for your project, so create a virtual environment (ideally inside your project folder) using command

```
py -m pip install --user .venv
```